# Can ideal functionalities share variables

Tags: security-definition, universal-composability

I am trying to define an ideal world for a protocol that requires two functionalities to interact with each other. Lets call them $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$.

Now $\mathcal{F}_1$ maintains a list of some values, say $L$. This list $L$ may be updated with every activation. Any party queries this $\mathcal{F}_1$ , the list $L$ is updated. Now $\mathcal{F}_2$ needs to use this $L$ to say verify inputs that it receives from the parties. Can $L$ simply be a shared global list, so that $\mathcal{F}_2$ can verify directly. Or do I need to do something more complicated like have $\mathcal{F}_2$ query $\mathcal{F}_1$ each time (to retrieve $L$ )a party sends an input to $\mathcal{F}_2$.

Basically, are global variables allowed in UC? What are the things I need to keep in mind, if I have shared global variables in the ideal world.